# How to convert (5,) numpy array to (5,1)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to convert (5,) numpy array to (5,1)?

And how to convert backwards from (5,1) to (5,)?

What is the purpose of (5,) array, why is one dimension omitted? I mean why we didn't always use (5,1) form?

Does this happen only with 1D and 2D arrays or does it happen across 3D arrays, like can (2,3,) array exist?

**UPDATE:**

I managed to convert from (5,) to (5,1) by

```
a= np.reshape(a, (a.shape[0], 1))
```

but suggested variant looks simpler:

```
a = a[:, None] or a = a[:, np.newaxis]
```

To convert from (5,1) to (5,) [np.ravel](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) can be used

```
a= np.ravel(a)
```

Comment: .. if those are meant to be answers, why are they comments?

Comment: There's no need for "placeholder" comments, and it can often take more than two minutes to find a good dup target anyway.

Comment: Why should there be a 2nd dimension?  Are you a MATLAB refugee? :)

Comment: @hpaulj Sometimes sklearn requires a 2 dimensional array of features

Comment: @hpaulj yes, there is no such annoying thing in matlab.

Comment: In the good old days, everything in MATLAB was 2d.  Expanding to 3d or more was a major innovation.  To get a of flavor that try the `np.matrix` class.

Comment: I don't think the duplicate suggestion is good, because none of the answers it suggests will work in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A numpy array with shape `(5,)` is a 1 dimensional array while one with shape `(5,1)` is a 2 dimensional array. The difference is subtle, but can alter some computations in a major way. One has to be specially careful since these changes can be bull-dozes over by operations which flatten all dimensions, like `np.mean` or `np.sum`.

In addition to @m-massias's answer, consider the following as an example:

```
17:00:25 [2]: import numpy as np
17:00:31 [3]: a = np.array([1,2])
17:00:34 [4]: b = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
17:00:45 [6]: b * a
      Out[6]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [3, 8]])
17:00:50 [7]: b * a[:,None] # Different result!
      Out[7]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [6, 8]])
```

`a` has shape `(2,)` and it is [*broadcast*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) over the second dimension. So the result you get is that each row (the first dimension) is multiplied by the vector:

```
17:02:44 [10]: b * np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2]])
      Out[10]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [3, 8]])
```

On the other hand, `a[:,None]` has the shape `(2,1)` and so the orientation of the vector is known to be a column. Hence, the result you get is from the following operation (where each column is multiplied by `a`):

```
17:03:39 [11]: b * np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2]])
      Out[11]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [6, 8]])
```

I hope that sheds some light on how the two arrays will behave differently.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a new axis to an array `a` by doing `a = a[:, None]` or `a = a[:, np.newaxis]`

As far as "one dimension omitted", I don't really understand your question, because it has no end : the array could be `(5, 1, 1)`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

**Use reshape() function**
e.g. 
open python terminal and type following:

```
    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> a = np.random.random(5)
    >>> a
    array([0.85694461, 0.37774476, 0.56348081, 0.02972139, 0.23453958])
    >>> a.shape
    (5,)
    >>> b = a.reshape(5, 1)
    >>> b.shape
    (5, 1)
```